# If Template arg is function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

If I have a template class

```
template <class T>
class foo
{  /**/  }
```

How will i find if `T` is a function pointer?

There is `std::is_pointer` and `std::is_function` but no `is_function_pointer`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the pointer and check if the result is a function.

Here is code sample:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>


template<class T> constexpr bool foo() {
    using T2 = std::remove_pointer_t<T>;
    return std::is_function<T2>::value;
}


int main() {
    std::cout << "Is function? " << foo<void (int)>()
              << "; is function pointer? " << foo<int (*)()>() << "\n";

}
```

Comment: is function pointer  de-referenced same way as that of normal pointer?? `int (*f)()` de-referenced as `*f()` ??

Comment: @WARhead, do not dereference it. Use `remove_pointer_t` as shown above.

Comment: [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/remove_pointer/] says there is no `_t` after `remove_pointer` simply `std::remove_pointer`

Comment: It is wrong. There certainly is `remove_pointer_t`, it has been added in C++14.

Comment: I think i'm still using c++11 though (I'm compiling in Visual studio 2015)

Comment: @WARhead, in this case, use `using T2 = typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type`.